# React app not loading after I added a new component

Tags: reactjs

I have made a header.js component in a separate file in React, and i add it to my App.js file, but it's not loading in the front-end. I am not getting any errors. In the browser is showing an empty page, before adding the header the app was viewing perfectly.

header.js

```
import React from 'react';


function Header()
{
     return(
        <Header style={headerStyle}>
            <h1> Todo List </h1>
                 </Header>

     )
}

const headerStyle = {
    background: '#333',
    color: '#fff',
    textAlign: 'center',
    padding : '10px'
}


export default Header;


app.js

 render(){
    //console.log(this.state.todos)
  return (
    <div className="App">
       <Header />
      <Todos todos ={this.state.todos} markComplete ={this.markComplete} delTodo={this.delTodo} />
    </div>
  );
  }
}
```

And I import header file in app.js file

On the terminal its display this : Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.
browser showing empty page

Comment: It will be better if u show code rather than explaining.

Comment: Try to read your question from another person's POV, would you be able to answer it without seeing any code?

Comment: @ByrisettiHemanth  I added an image of my code. I just noticed is not showing . Am sorry about that, I will paste the code now

Comment: Add this code in your question, not as comments

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I added an image showing my code snippets , I can't see it in the post .

Comment: Images of code are not encouraged, post your actual code

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava thanks so much for the corrections , have added the code.

Comment: Check the fact that you are returning `Header` from inside `Header`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava ooh my days, Thanks so much I really appreciate . Problem solved is now showing . After I changed <Header> to <header>. Thanks